# Method Range of Object Global failed when using named range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a vba script, that runs a select script in SQL and pastes it into a named range. Below is my code;

```
Option Explicit
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rcrds As ADODB.Recordset
Sub runQuery(strSQL As String, rngResults As Range)

    Set rcrds = New ADODB.Recordset
    rcrds.Open strSQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    rngResults.ClearContents
    rngResults.CopyFromRecordset rcrds

End Sub
Public Sub Update_Scorecard_2()

    Dim ssql As String
    Dim myrange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

        cnt.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=ODSPRD01;user ID=DWH_ADH;password=mypassword;"

    Call runQuery(Range("DATA_DUMP_SQL").Value, Range("DATA_DUMP"))

    cnt.Close

End Sub
```

I am getting the error "Method Range of Object Global failed". I understand this is most likely an issue with vba not knowing what sheet to look in, but my understanding was that this should not be an issue with a named range? I have tried setting variables explitely from the named ranges but this has not worked either.

The error is occurring on this line:

```
Call runQuery(Range("DATA_DUMP_SQL").Value, Range("DATA_DUMP"))
```

What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Are the `DATA_DUMP_SQL` and `DATA_DUMP` named ranges defined with a *Workbook* scope or a *Worksheet* scope? Formulas ► Defined Names ►Name Manager ► Edit Name ► Scope.

Comment: Is that error message the complete message you are seeing? Is there any error code?

Comment: @ jeeped, that was the issues. I've now changed these to worksheet scope. Many thanks. If you want to put that as the answer I'll accept it.